# A package for sort algorithms - v2

Tags: javascript, sorting

Looking for general feedback and praise.  This is for learning an not implementation as I would expect the built is sort algos to be much faster.

Addressed issues here:

[A package for sort algorithms](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38651/a-package-for-sort-algorithms)

```
/***************************************************************************************************
    **ALGORITHMS
    ***************************************************************************************************/

    // self used to hold client or server side global
    (function (self) {

        "use strict";

        // holds (Pub)lic properties
        var Pub = {},

            // holds (Priv)ate properties
            Priv = {},

            // holds "imported" library properties
            $A;

        (function manageGlobal() {

            // Priv.g holds the single global variable, used to hold all packages
            Priv.g = '$A';

            if (self[Priv.g] && self[Priv.g].pack && self[Priv.g].pack.utility) {
                self[Priv.g].pack.algo = true;
                $A = self[Priv.g];
            } else {
                throw new Error("algo requires utility module");
            }
        }());

        Pub.swap = function (arr, i, j) {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        };

        // checks to see if sorted
        Pub.isSorted = function (arr) {
            var i,
                length = arr.length;
            for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

        // repeatedly orders two items ( a bubble ) at a time
        Pub.bubbleSort = function (arr) {
            var index_outer,
                index_inner,
                swapped = false,
                length = arr.length;
            for (index_outer = 0; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
                swapped = false;
                for (index_inner = 0; index_inner < length - index_outer; index_inner++) {
                    if (arr[index_inner] > arr[index_inner + 1]) {
                        Pub.swap(arr, index_inner, index_inner + 1);
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!swapped) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return arr;
        };

        // repeatedly finds minimum and places it the next index
        Pub.selectionSort = function (arr) {
            var index_outer,
                index_inner,
                index_min,
                length = arr.length;
            for (index_outer = 1; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
                index_min = index_outer;
                for (index_inner = index_outer + 1; index_inner < length; index_inner++) {
                    if (arr[index_inner] < arr[index_min]) {
                        index_min = index_inner;
                    }
                }
                if (index_outer !== index_min) {
                    Pub.swap(arr, index_outer, index_min);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        };

        // repeatedly places next item in correct spot using a "shift"
        Pub.insertionSort = function (arr) {
            var index_outer,
                index_inner,
                value,
                length = arr.length;
            for (index_outer = 0; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
                value = arr[index_outer];

                // JavaScript optimization - index_inner >=0 is removed
                // as the array index will return undefined for a negative index
                for (index_inner = index_outer - 1; (arr[index_inner] > value);
                        index_inner--) {
                    arr[index_inner + 1] = arr[index_inner];
                }
                arr[index_inner + 1] = value;
            }
            return arr;
        };

        // module complete, release to outer scope
        self[Priv.g] = $A.extendSafe(self[Priv.g], Pub);
    }(this));
```

Comment: Is your code faster than the built-in `sort()`, and if not, what is the purpose of this library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the reason for performing internal initialization inside the `manageGlobal` function? You're already inside a function, and you're operating on its local variables.

Here are some thoughts on the insertion sort (chosen at random):

- You can start `index_outer` at `1` since the inner loop is empty at `0`.
- Use camelCase for variable and function names
- Try to find names that are more descriptive. For example, `upperIndex` since it's the moving upper bound and `shiftIndex` since it's the index of the element to shift up.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the points I already mentioned in your previous post, I would like to point out that the JavaScript way of preserving the global object is not passing it as a parameter, but using `Function.prototype.call`, effectively turning your last line into

```
    }).call(this);
```

Also note that this code breaks if not executed in the global scope - which may always be the case if you use module packaging scripts such as RequireJS.

Comment: What is your reason for this?  Functionally there is no difference between using `call()` vs the way I do it.

Comment: Mainly everyone reading your code will immediately know what `this` means whereas people who do not know Python might not recognize `self`. Additionally it's a convention thing, it's the way big libraries do it. Also, you should stick to the name the language you use uses, i.e. you could change every `self` to a `this` in Python, but you don't - because it's counter intuitive.

Comment: jQuery does it the way I do it - just FYI.

Comment: Ultimately it's of course your choice, but jQuery doesn't change the 'name' of the global object. Inside the closure `window` is still `window`. In your situation, where your library could also be used on the server side and the global object isn't `window`, I would just stick to `this` and the most concise way to do that is to use `call` IMHO. And you're asking for our opinion on your code ;)

Comment: O.K. will update.