# A package for sort algorithms - v3

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Addressed both issues in this [codereview post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39619/a-package-for-sort-algorithms-v2).

Fixed the indexing issue and the call mechanism of the function expression.

Looking for perfect code.  Hope this is the last rev.

```
    /***************************************************************************************************
    **ALGORITHMS
    ***************************************************************************************************/

    // self used to hold client or server side global
    (function () {

        "use strict";

        // holds (Pub)lic properties
        var Pub = {},

            // holds (Priv)ate properties
            Priv = {},

            // holds "imported" library properties
            $A;

        (function manageGlobal() {

            // Priv.g holds the single global variable, used to hold all packages
            Priv.g = '$A';

            if (this[Priv.g] && this[Priv.g].pack && this[Priv.g].pack.utility) {
                this[Priv.g].pack.algo = true;
                $A = this[Priv.g];
            } else {
                throw new Error("algo requires utility module");
            }
        }());

        Pub.swap = function (arr, i, j) {
            var temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        };

        // checks to see if sorted
        Pub.isSorted = function (arr) {
            var i,
                length = arr.length;
            for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[i - 1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

        // repeatedly orders two items ( a bubble ) at a time
        Pub.bubbleSort = function (arr) {
            var index_outer,
                index_inner,
                swapped = false,
                length = arr.length;
            for (index_outer = 0; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
                swapped = false;
                for (index_inner = 0; index_inner < length - index_outer; index_inner++) {
                    if (arr[index_inner] > arr[index_inner + 1]) {
                        Pub.swap(arr, index_inner, index_inner + 1);
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!swapped) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return arr;
        };

        // repeatedly finds minimum and places it the next index
        Pub.selectionSort = function (arr) {
            var index_outer,
                index_inner,
                index_min,
                length = arr.length;
            for (index_outer = 0; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
                index_min = index_outer;
                for (index_inner = index_outer + 1; index_inner < length; index_inner++) {
                    if (arr[index_inner] < arr[index_min]) {
                        index_min = index_inner;
                    }
                }
                if (index_outer !== index_min) {
                    Pub.swap(arr, index_outer, index_min);
                }
            }
            return arr;
        };

        // repeatedly places next item in correct spot using a "shift"
        Pub.insertionSort = function (arr) {
            var index_outer,
                index_inner,
                value,
                length = arr.length;
            for (index_outer = 1; index_outer < length; index_outer++) {
                value = arr[index_outer];

                // JavaScript optimization - index_inner >=0 is removed
                // as the array index will return undefined for a negative index
                for (index_inner = index_outer - 1; (arr[index_inner] > value);
                        index_inner--) {
                    arr[index_inner + 1] = arr[index_inner];
                }
                arr[index_inner + 1] = value;
            }
            return arr;
        };

        // module complete, release to outer scope
        this[Priv.g] = $A.extendSafe(this[Priv.g], Pub);
    }).call(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would remove `Pub.swap` and copy its code where you need it.

That's because function calls are expensive, so better avoid calling a function at each iteration if possible.

And try to cache the expressions in loop's condition. For example,

```
var lengthMinusIndexOuter = length - index_outer;
for (index_inner = 0; index_inner < lengthMinusIndexOuter; index_inner++) {
```

instead of

```
for (index_inner = 0; index_inner < length - index_outer; index_inner++)
```

Comment: The caching sound like a good idea, but I don't think a function call is so costly that it is worth making the code less DRY.

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com You would be surprised of how costly are function calls: see slides 10~19 of [Extreme JavaScript Performance](http://www.slideshare.net/madrobby/extreme-javascript-performance) slideshow

Comment: over 3 years old...

Comment: @www.arcmarks.com Well, newer javascript engines are more optimized and can do more operations per second. But inline code is still faster than function calls, because inline code runs faster too.